# Not able to get file name from file uploader

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to fetch whole path from file uploader at server side..It's working in IE..I got full path in IE but not in chrome may be because of security issue..Please let me know if I made any mistake in my code and if it's correct then suggest me solution..

**HTML**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AppEditorHome", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" id="upload_file" style="display: none;" name="file" onchange="uploadedFileDetail()" />
}
```

**js**

```
    function uploadedFileDetail() {
        var formdata = new FormData();
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('upload_file');
        var filename = fileInput.files[0].name;
        formdata.append(fileInput.files[0].name, fileInput.files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '@Url.Action("uploadeFile", "Home")');
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) { debugger; }
        }
    }
```

**controller**

```
    public ActionResult uploadeFile() { return View(); }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult uploadeFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = Request.Files.Count;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                file = Request.Files[0];
                var clientPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(file.FileName);
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
                var data = new
                {
                    uploaded = Request.Files
                };
                return Json(data);
            }
            return Json("");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Json(""); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot get the full path. It is a security issue (your server should not know anything about a clients file structure) and it was only able to be done in older versions of IE.

Comment: Is there any solution available for that??? In my app client can upload any file and I have to fetch that file to get content of it @StephenMuecke

Comment: What do you mean. Once you upload the file to the server, you just save it on your server and then you can do whatever you want with it (you cannot access a file - or any other resource on a client computer - the web would have not existed very long if that had ever been possible)

Comment: What I have to do basically is: when user upload file then I have to get file's path and have to get content of file and display on client side..so I have get to know client side its not possible to get file path but its same at server side also..

Comment: When a user uploads a file you already have the contents of that file - that what it does - it streams the a copy of the file to your server - you can do what ever you want with it once its been uploaded - just save it somewhere on the server.

Comment: Do you mean I can get content client side and save uploaded file on server side?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113141/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-debin).